# Check if a thread is interrupted?

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

I just want to get know about if this thread is interrupting or not if I'm doing it right?
please give me hint if I'm wrong

```
public void run(){
  int i;
  while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
    for(i=1;i<=100;i++){

      System.out.println("THREAD VALUE AFTER 1 SECOND IS: "+i);

      if(i==3){
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        gotoInform();
        break;
      }
      try{
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);////to sleep the Thread for 1 Second (1000ms)
      }
      catch(Exception e){            
        System.out.printf("Error"+e);            
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'm not sure this code makes too much sense. When you call `currentThread().interrupt()` you're obviously not interrupting it from a blocking operation. All that does is set the `interrupted` flag which will only be checked after your `for` loop finishes.

Comment: To start from the basics: what are you trying to accomplish? Have you tried running your code? What does it do? How is what it does different from what you want it to do?

Comment: Sorry I'm not able to get you please can you explain easily?

Comment: I just want to stop a thread at given point/flag say when i==3 its simple!

Comment: The thread will stop on its own when you exit the `run` method

Comment: @Junaid Then `return` from the `run()` method. Stopping the current thread isn't even *close* to what "interrupting" is supposed to accomplish. (And the javadocs for `interrupt()` tell you what that is.)

Comment: @JunaidHassan, `interrupt()` allows one thread to affect another thread. In your code, there is a single entry point, and you don't spawn a thread. So clearly, your logic is confined to a single thread. Which means `interrupt()` is an overkill at best, but usually an *abuse*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is wrong, because if `sleep` finds that the thread is interrupted, it will throw an `InterruptedException` *and clear the interrupted flag*. You then swallow that exception, suppressing any record that the thread was ever interrupted. Instead, you should write something more like this:

```
public void run(){
    for(int i=1;i<=100;i++){

        System.out.println("THREAD VALUE AFTER 1 SECOND IS: "+i);

        if(i==3){
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            gotoInform();
            break;
        }
        try{
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
        }
        catch(final Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            if(e instanceof InterruptedException) {
                // just in case this Runnable is actually called directly,
                // rather than in a new thread, don't want to swallow the
                // flag:
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

(Note: I'm assuming that this is not "real" code, but rather, that you're just trying to learn how thread interruption works. In "real" code, you should almost never need to interrupt the current thread in this way.)

Comment: will it stop/or kill the current thread securely and surely? I mean it this a good approach for any thread to stop/interrupt using any flag/point of value?

Comment: Looks like the code will never get to the sleep if it self-interrupts.  If _other_ threads interrupt this thread then it will work.  And it is always a good idea to do this. +1.

Comment: still it has interrupted Exception !!! what i should do for it it is still throwing interrupted exception?

Comment: @ruakh and @ Gray
will it stop/or kill the current thread securely and surely? I mean it this a good approach for any thread to stop/interrupt using any flag/point of value?

Comment: I FOUND THIS 100% LOGICAL +1 HATS OFF@ raukh

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before, a thread interrupting itself is pointless (unless used to re-interrupt itself after catching an InterruptedException) .  You're basically using the thread's internal interrupted flag as a conditional variable here - which while it may work is not at all what it's supposed to be used for and will be confusing to anyone else who would need to read your code.  Use a loop counter instead as suggested above to make the code much cleaner.

Also, your statement:

```
System.out.println("THREAD VALUE AFTER 1 SECOND IS: "+i);
```

is erroneous as it will execute immediately the first time through the loop (when the time is closer to zero seconds).

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to get know about if this thread is interrupting or not if I'm doing it right?

@ruakh is correct that it is *always* a good idea to re-interrupt a thread once `InterruptedException` is thrown.

However, if the goal of your code is to self-interrupt and no other threads will interrupt the running thread, then you will never get to the `sleep()` call since `break;` is called after the thread is interrupted.

If the thread is always just self interrupted then I would just use a flag.  Something like:

```
boolean done = false;
while (!done) {
   ...
   if(i==3){
        done = true;
        ...
   }
}
```

Even though you interrupt your thread, you then call `gotoInform()` which may call `wait()`or `sleep()` itself and cause an `InterruptedException`.  You'll need to make sure that code behaves well and re-interrupts the thread if so.